# Get variables from several interrelated functions in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to get **variables** from several interrelated functions during XML parsing and put them into **arrays**. The code is:

```
function readChapters($reader) {
    while($reader->read()) {
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            $chapter = readValue($reader);
        }
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            readModules($reader);
        }
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

function readModules($reader) {
    while($reader->read()) {
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            readModule($reader);
        }
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            return($reader);
        }
    }
}

function readModule($reader) {
    while($reader->read()) {
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            $topic = readValue($reader);
        }
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            $description = readValue($reader);
        }
    }
}

function readValue($reader) {
    while($reader->read()) {
        if( /* condition here */ ) {
            return $reader->readInnerXML();
        }
    }
}

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('example.xml');

$current = 0;
$topics_list = array();

$chapterName = "";          // want to add $chapter
$topicName = "";            // want to add $topic
$descriptionText = "";      // want to add $description

while($reader->read()) {
    if(// condition here) {
        readChapters($reader);
    }
    $topics_list[$current] = array();
    $topics_list[$current]['chapter'] = $chapterName;
    $topics_list[$current]['topic'] = $topicName;
    $topics_list[$current]['description'] = $descriptionText;
}
$reader->close();
print_r($topics_list);
```

**Problem:** How to get *$chapter*, *$topic*, *$description* variables from outside of these functions in order to put them into arrays? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** The XML document structure is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyB1U.png), and the expected structure of Array():

```
Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [chapter] => Chapter_name1
                    [topic] => Topic_name1
                    [description] => Content_of_the_topic1
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [chapter] => Chapter_name1
                    [topic] => Topic_name2
                    [description] => Content_of_the_topic2
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [chapter] => Chapter_name2
                    [topic] => Topic_name2
                    [description] => Content_of_the_topic2
            )
            .....
        )
```

Comment: Why not pass an empty array to readChapters as a second param, and then populate the array as you go from one function to the next?  Or am I not understanding what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dylan, I'm trying to achieve 3 values from a given xml document, which has branched elements. Above mentioned functions retrieving all needed these 3 values, but I want put them into multidimensional array, which is constructed outside of these functions.
About empty array to readChapters as a second param could you please explain in detail? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially using a set of function to build a data structure using data from an XML object. That means that each function should return the data structure it's named for: readChapters() should return a chapter structure (and should probably be named readChapter(), since I think it's only reading one chapter, correct?), and so on. I don't know what your XML looks like or what your desired data structure looks like, but you'll want something like this:

```
function readChapter($reader) {
    $chapter = array();
    while (// condition) {
         if (// something)
              $chapter['chapter'] = readValue($reader);
         elseif (// something else)
              $chapter['topic'] = readValue($reader);
         // etc
    }

    return $chapter;
}
```

Then in your main loop below, you can have this:

```
while ($reader->read()) {
    if (// condition here) {
        $topics_list[] = readChapter($reader);
    }
}
```

Hope that gets you closer to something you can build!

Comment: each function goes through the structure mentioned above (see updated part of the topic) and retrieves values (in loop) from the particular parts of the document and you are right it's only reading of xml. My code already prints all chapters, topics and descriptions. The only thing is I want to put them into multidimentional array, which structure mentioned also in above. I tried your hint, but its print an empty Array(), have you any idea?

Comment: The concept missing in your original solution is *returning the correct values* from your functions. Your original `readValue` function is the only one with an appropriate return value - check the return values of your other functions. For example, your `readChapter` function should return an array that captures a single chapter. Those individual return values can be compiled into the final `$topics_list` array that you want. You can find more about return values in PHP functions here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/functions